# Prove that it is a connected set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

I have been trying this problem but I do not see it, any clue ...

Shows that the set:

$$D =\left \{ (x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^{2}: x^{2}+y^{2}\leq 1 \right \} \setminus (0,0) $$
is a connected set.

I tried to do it by the definition of disconnection, first I assumed that it is not true therefore it has a non-trivial disconnection and it can be noticed that those A and B that exist because they have a trivial disconnection, one must be closed so that they can be the set Initially, therefore there would be a contradiction, I think, but I think that is not formal at all, so how could I do it?

Comment: It is not too hard to show it's path connected and then you're done

Comment: @Fshike you're right, if it is connected by paths then it is connected, but 
I was trying to do it by defining disconnection, is there a way to do it like this?

Comment: A set is disconnected it it has a proper nonempty subset that is both open and closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @FShrike says, it's easiest to approach via path-connectedness. For example, to get from a point $d_0$ to a point $d_1$, you could first go around the circle to match the angle of $d_1$, then go straight along a radius.

It seems that you prefer to prove the result by contradiction, starting by assuming a disconnection. This is probably harder than the approach above, but here's one idea. Suppose there's a disconnection $D = A_0 \cup A_1$. Then choose $d_0 \in A_0$ and $d_1 \in A1$, and draw a simple path $p$ between those points, as above. That gives us a disconnection $(p \cap A_0) \cup (p \cap A_1)$ of $p$, which is impossible since $p$ is a continuous image of a connected set.

Comment: It is true thank you very much